# |c| Series 1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+....nx^(n-1)

Tags: c, series

First of all, I searched and all questions I found are similar but not exactly this one.

This is my first post here, I'm a beginner in programming and currently learning to code in C.
Been struggling with this code for about 5 hours now.

The question is create a program in C, using only loops (and not using `pow()`, using `stdio.h` library only).

The question is to get the user to give you two numbers - X and N 
the program will print The result of the following equation:

1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+....+**nx^(n-1)**

For example for the input of - X=2 N=3

```
1*2^0 + 2*2^1 + 3*2^2
```

What the program will print is "**17**"

This is my attempt so far, I got to the Power function but I cant find a way to incorporate into the programm itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)    
{
    int i, j=0, b = 0;
    float x, n;
    double sum = 0, sumt=0;
    do{
        printf("Please enter two numbers \n");
        flushall;
        scanf("%f %f", &n, &x);
    } while (x <= 0);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        sum = x*x;
    }

    sumt += sum;
    printf("%f", sum);
}
```

Comment: Google Horner's algorithm/method - this will either help or confuse you

Comment: What exactly seems to be a problem? Have you ever written any `c` code? Do you know how to calculate `x^n` without `pow()`?

Comment: Please post your attempt - this helps get you the answer you require.

Comment: Edited in my attempt so far , it gets as far as the power function. for a single numbers ..but im trying to find a way to get it to do the series now but it keeps breaking apart

Comment: Did you notice the "single numbers" are corresponding to your `i` ?

Comment: What is `flushall;` ?

Comment: Some advice, use double letters for your loop indexes, this will easen finding them in large files. ii instead of i

Also, avoid starting loops in 1 (unless you really have a good reason to), it will get very confusing when manipulating strings, for instance. Start on zero instead

`for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)`->`for(ii=0;ii<n;ii++)` also, in your code; sum is always x^2 after the loop, I don't think that's what you want to do

Comment: It's `int main(void)`. I took the liberty to fix as not to spread the `void main` disease.

Comment: No matter what i do i cant get this horror to work ..would love a working solution now :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to create an implementation of `pow`, you will need to take advantage of the relationship between the terms of the expression.

The `n`-th term is `nx^(n-1)`. The `n-1`-the term is `(n-1)x^(n-2)`.

If we denote the `n`-th term as `T(n)` and denote the `n-1`-th term as `T(n-1)`,

```
T(n) = T(n-1)*x*n/(n-1)
```

Given the starting value of the first term,

```
T(1) = 1
```

you can compute the subsequent terms using the above formula.

The following code should work.

```
// Initialize the values for N=1
term = 1;
sum = 1;

// Iterate starting from 2
for (i = 2; i <= n; i++){
    term *= x*i/(i-1);
    sum += term;
}
```

Comment: well he'll get a mention for that. And he clearly owes you a beer

Comment: @LuisSieira, it's not clear to me whether the instructor was expecting an implementation of `pow` or hoping that the students will find the implementation I suggested.

Comment: If they're starting learning programming, it sounds logical to make an implementation including input, output, assignation, basic arithmetics, flow control and function declaration. I'd say they expect the pow thing, but I like your approach. I've never been a calculus guy, it was very frustrating to me in college, but I've always found it beautiful.

Comment: @LuisSieira, I agree with you about calculus being beautiful. Some times it takes a special instructor or author to ignite the spark inside. I hope that sparks gets ignited inside you :)

Comment: I think this answer is even more complicated for me then the question ..heh ... But i think im getting close.

and as for the instructor , she is pure evil . :D

Comment: So..where do i send the beer to?...it worked...im gonna bury myself in the sand now for not being able to figure this out on my own :(

Comment: @Emeter, thanks for the beer. It's the sentiment that counts :)

Comment: The answer seems so simple now after i look at it..But i don't believe i would've figured out the math on my own  (speciall the x*i/(i-1) part).
how hard is this question really?..should i really feel bad for not being able to reach this answer on my own?

Comment: @Emeter, you are welcome to beat yourself up. I do that sometimes while playing chess :) It's better to learn from the experience and move on.

Answer (score 1):

The working Program based on the tips given by the almighty @R_Sahu (And others ;D)
**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)  
{
int i, j = 0, c = 0;
float x, n, b = 0;
double term, sum;
do {
    printf("Enter Two Numbers\n");
    flushall;
    scanf("%f%f", &n, &x);
} while (x < 0);
for (i = 2; i < n + 2; i++)
{

    term = 1;
    sum = 1;


    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        term *= x*i / (i - 1);
        sum += term;
    }
}
printf("The answer is %.lf  ", sum);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I will not give you the code, but the reasoning you should follow

First you have to somehow get the data from the user (as a parameter, from stdio... whatever)

```
x = getFromUser
n = getFromUser
```

You will then need to init a temporary result

```
result = 0
```

How many times do you have to add? -> Exactly n times

```
for(ii=0;ii<n;ii++) {
    result = result + pow((ii*x),(ii-1)) //There is something missing here, I'll let you guess what
}
```

But wait; you cannot use pow. So you have to program it by yourself (I guess that's the idea of the exercise)

then you need a function, and it has to return an int (actually, it may return even irrational numbers, but I don't think they will require you to do that)

```
int customPow(int base, int exponent) {
 //Put your for in here, and may the pow be with you
}
```

Comment: He stated no use of `pow` function .

Comment: I know, thats the point of my answer, he is supposed to program this function by himself

Comment: No, no, no. These simple series sum can be computed in O(n) without any additional custom `pow`s...

Comment: Yes ,excatly there is no need to create additional function .

Comment: Yes, it is this http://www.ilemaths.net/img/forum_img/0289/forum_289183_2.png, but anyway, he is required to use loops and such, I don't think it is a calculus exercise

Comment: @LuisSieira Now you have pointed to an O(1) method, which is nice. But I am talking about O(n) method, while you are talking about O(n^2) method.

Comment: Well , You are defiantly giving me into the right direction  , i guess ill keep trying to play around with the code until it actually works .(or ill burn my college in frustration ..what ever comes first )

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the code yourself, but the general idea is as follows:

Create your own pow function which returns x*n.

```
int pow(int x, int n){
   //use a for or while loop to calculate x (*x)n times. 
   //pay attention to the base cases (i.e., when n = 0, or 1 etc)
}

ans = 0;
for(i = 0 to N-1){
   ans = ans + pow(x,i-1)*i;
}
```

Comment: As answered by @RSahu you don't even need a `pow()` function. It's a waste of execution time, since for each term `n` you already have `pow(x, n-1)`.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but he said he's a beginner to programming so I suggested an approach I think is easier to follow. Compared to the more efficient way which requires some mathematical knowledge.

Comment: That's a bit of an assumption. If the OP is a beginner in programming but tackling a series summation, I would guess he does have some mathematical knowledge.